# In FB Graph API Explorer, what's the difference between /me/likes and /{id}/likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I think this is a basic question.

When I use the API explorer with the path `/me/likes`, I get a list of my likes.  My access token has the `user_likes` permission.

When I change `me` to my facebook id and use the same token as above, I get back an empty list.  I've verified the id is the correct one because exploring `/me` does correctly return my name.

What is the semantic difference between `me` and my id?

Comment: `me` is who- (user) or whatever (page) the token belongs to. _“I've verified the id is the correct one because exploring /me does correctly return my name.”_ - what does `me` returning your name have to do with any id? You’re likely not using the _correct_ id - you’re aware those are app-scoped, right? The id that `me` shows is the only correct one for your app to use.

Comment: The id is the facebook id of the user for the token.  I assumed I could get the likes for that facebook id, and it would be the same as getting the likes for `me`.

Comment: It is. You must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: I described what I did on the graph api explorer, so if it's working for you I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: What do you get for `me?fields=id,likes` and `{id}?fields=id,likes`, using the same access token?

Comment: Whoa!  There are two different ids in play.  Going to `https://www.facebook.com/{id}` for either id redirects to my personal page.  And both return the same 'name' field.   What's the difference?

Comment: Quote: _"you’re aware those are app-scoped, right?"_ ... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_610616752452545

Answer (score 0):

The token from the Graph API for an 'app', so it is interpreting `me` according to it's own app-scoped id for `me`.  The id I had been substituting was my accounts original id.   Both ids point to the same person (me).

Thanks CBroe.